# How does one make a 2D array of dataframes in R? (each cell is a dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array

How does one make a 2D array of dataframes in R, where each cell is a dataframe containing two rows of a given spreadsheet?

• Each column has the same number of rows.

• Each cell has a unique combination of columns, but the cell's columns are not unique

**Another way of thinking of this is I want to translate the following Java to R:**

```
DataFrame[][] tests = new DataFrame[6][32];
tests[1][1] = value;
```

Back to R, "value" is defined as:

```
value = table[,c(x,y)]
```

where x and y are variables indicating the columns of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you show the dput of a small example

Comment: It's called "list-columns". Tidyverse pipes tend to do it with `tidyr::nest`, though it can be done in base R (with a bit more work). See `tidyr::nest`.

Comment: You can make a `matrix` by adding dimensions to a `vector`, and a `list` is a `vector`. Thus, if you have a `list` of `data.frame`s like `l <- list(mtcars, iris, airquality, anscombe)`, you could convert it to a `matrix` as simply as doing `m <- matrix(l, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)`. Not sure if that's along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: For a `data.frame`, you could wrap `m` in `data.frame` (though it doesn't print as nicely to the console) or alternatively, wrap it with `tibble` or `data.table` depending on what you prefer to work with. With base R, to get to a `data.frame` directly, you need to use `I()` to create `list` columns, eg: `df <- data.frame(v1 = I(list(mtcars, iris)), v2 = I(list(airquality, anscombe)))`

Comment: @akrun what is "dput"?